# Why is VisualStudio 2017 telling me "...element is not supported in this context"?

Tags: visual-studio, xsd

MCVE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
    targetNamespace="http://versionschema.org/xmlns/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vs="http://versionschema.org/xmlns/"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xsd:element name="VersionSchema" type="vs:VersionSchema"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="VersionSchema" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <!-- VS says: "minOccurs and maxOccurs not allowed ^^^^ -->

        <xsd:element name="Field" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <!-- ^^^ VS says: The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:element' is not supported in this context -->
        </xsd:element>

    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Referring to [https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#POSchema](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#PO), I don't see why it's complaining. Any ideas whether or what it is I am doing wrong here?

Note that it is my goal to write this up such that there can be only one VersionSchema object in an XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are thinking about this from a programming language perspective in which you would add fields to a class or type by placing them as elements inside of the container.

For XML Schemas this is not true. The reason for this is that in its most strict definition XML is order dependent.

You can write yourself a schema which accepts the following XML.

```
<Root>
    <Element/>
    <Test/> 
</Root>
```

But rejects a very similiar XML Structure:

```
<Root>
    <Test/>
    <Element/>
</Root>
```

One of the reasons you can do so is because a more strict XML schema is easier to guard against attacks and malicious input. It is therefore always required to specifiy in the XML Schema wether or not the order in which elements appear matter. This is why an element such as the `xsd:sequence` is required. Note that this can quickly become a tripwire for your serialization and deserialization.

Your orignal XML could therefore be stated as follows but might be stated differently depending on your exact use case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
  targetNamespace="http://versionschema.org/xmlns/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vs="http://versionschema.org/xmlns/"
  elementFormDefault="unqualified"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xsd:element name="VersionSchema" type="vs:VersionSchema"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="VersionSchema">
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xsd:element name="Field" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The relevant sections would be [3.4 Complex Type Definitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Complex_Type_Definitions) and [2.2.3 Model Group Components](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Model_Group_Summary). It states that

> The XML representation for a complex type definition schema component
>   is a `<complexType>` element information item. [...] Content:

```
(annotation?, (simpleContent | complexContent | (openContent?, (group| all | choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?), assert*)))
```

Note that in order to place an `<element>` into the complex type you either have to use `complexContent`, a `group` or modelgroup elements like `all`, `choice` or `sequence`. It is the same for `complexContent` which cannot contain `<element>` but only `extension` which can only contain

```
(annotation?, openContent?, ((group | all | choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?), assert*))
```

> [...]There are three varieties of model group:
>
> Sequence (the element information items match the particles in
>   sequential order); Conjunction (the element information items match
>   the particles, in any order); Disjunction (the element information
>   items match one or more of the particles). Model Group, a kind of Term
>   [...] specifies a sequential (sequence), disjunctive (choice) or
>   conjunctive (all) interpretation of the {particles}.  This in turn
>   determines whether the element information item [children] validated
>   by the model group must:
>
> (sequence) correspond, in order, to the specified {particles};
>   (choice) correspond to exactly one of the specified {particles}; (all)
>   correspond to the specified {particles}. The elements can occur in any
>   order.

Even if stated slightly confusing in the model group section, a model group can itself only host the following content

```
(annotation?, (all | choice | sequence)?)
```

Which pretty much boils down to having to use all, choice and sequence when you would like to use `<element>`.

- all : (annotation?, (**element** | any | group)*)
- choice : (annotation?, (**element** | group | choice | sequence | any)*)
- sequence: (annotation?, (**element** | group | choice | sequence | any)*)

Comment: Yup, I see the sequence compositor in [the example I was loosely following](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#POSchema). I dropped it because I wanted to allow any of a number of elements in any order.  I have since discovered how to use the compositors to get a bit closer to what I am after, but because I put on bounty on this I couldn't not delete the question. Moving on to [new stumbling grounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605142/is-there-any-way-to-define-schema-for-elements-defined-in-the-data). Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Can you point me to "credible and/or official sources" for this requirement? I sort of reverse engineered it out of working with OxygenXML for a few hours over the week-end.

Comment: What is the difference between ordered and unordered? A server can stream ordered elements but has to buffer unordered elements in memory because a client could send them in any order.

Comment: I learned so much from this answer.  It saddens me that the question got so many down-votes without explanation.